# Multiple same values in Column A, need to find the greater date in column B

Tags: excel, if-statement, max, excel-2010, array-formulas

I'm stumped on a particular problem with some data that's imported to me. I have zero control over how the data is coming in. (Just to clarify that point).

I have two columns and 107,000 rows.

Column A has an ID#, Column B has the corresponding Date.

The issue I have is that Column A can have multiple identical values, and the corresponding date value in Column B has different or same dates.

I'm looking to add column C with a way to look up the cell in Column A, check it against the rest of column A, find any matches, and then return the Max/most recent date from column B for that ID#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and copied down to suit.

I'm afraid this could be quite slow.

I did not limit the range because I assumed *107,000 rows* was an approximation. However this is slow even for 1,000 rows, so for emphasis I repeat part of @XOR LX's comment:

> Even reducing the number of rows being referenced by a factor of 10 will have a significant improvement on calculation speed.

Comment: I'd been playing with that array formula all night! Thank you so much.

Comment: Even reducing the number of rows being referenced by a factor of 10 will have a significant improvement on calculation speed. Using entire column references within an array formula should be avoided at all costs, unless of course you genuinely have data comprising more than a million rows?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

Sort Columns A and B by Column B Newest to Oldest

Copy Column A (the ID#) to column D

Remove duplicates from column D

Use VLOOKUP in column E -- In E1 put VLOOKUP(D1,A:B,2,FALSE) and copy down

Columns D and E will now be unique ID numbers and the newest date.